# Why does this headset detection code execute twice?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've found several similar examples of headset state detection all using a switch to determine the state of the ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG broadcast.  I'm using this code in a service to trigger some other code when a headset is plugged in.

The following example does indeed detect the correct headset state but for some reason seems to run twice..ie. when I plug the headset in I get two "Headset is plugged" log messages in a row and another two "Headset was unplugged" when I unplug.  Any code I drop in the switch statement also gets called twice. I don't understand why this is so.  How can change this so my code is only called once?

```
public class HeadsetObserverService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "HeadsetObserverService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // Create a filter. We are interested in the Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG action
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);

    // Register a new HeadsetReceiver
    registerReceiver(new HeadsetReceiver(), filter);

    // We return START_STICKY. If our service gets destroyed, Android will try to restart it when resources are available.      
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class HeadsetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
                 Log.d("unplugged", "Headset was unplugged");

                 // Cancel notification here

            break;
            case 1:
                 Log.d("plugged", "Headset is plugged");

                 // Show notification

            break;

            default:
                Log.w("uh", "I have no idea what the headset state is");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will get some clue from [this stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092438/intent-action-headset-plug-is-received-when-activity-starts/4452190#4452190)

This problem is coming cause of [sendStickyBroadcast.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendStickyBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: I do appreciate the pointer but I haven't had much luck with this.  If the doubled log messages were the result of sendStickyBroadcast

Comment: I do appreciate the pointer but I haven't had much luck with this.  If the doubled log messages were the result of sendStickyBroadcast with the system sending both the last state and the current state I'm not clear why the messages are identical.  If I unplug the headphones I always see 2x "Headset was unplugged".  If this were due to StickyBroadcast shouldn't I see the last state "Headset is plugged" followed by the current state "Headset was unplugged"?

Comment: Upon further testing with multiple devices I think I may need to re-post this question.  The above code works properly on a Motorola Defy, Android v2.3.7. and only generates one log msg for each plug/unplug event.  On an LG P569 w/ Android 4.1.2 the code executes twice.