# How to detect if headphones was disconnected while media is playing

Tags: java, android-studio

How do I detect if the headphone was disconnected while the media is currently playing....Is there a state listener for that?

And how do I detect when the headphone is connected?

Comment: Yes Ryan, thank you very much! I've been searching all morning! I highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-check-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device), you can create a `BroadcastReceiver` that checks for an intent sent when headphones are plugged or unplugged.

```
broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG.equals(action)) {
               pluggedState = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
               if (pluggedState == 0) {
                  // headset not plugged in
               }
               if (pluggedState == 1) {
                  // headset plugged in
               }
            }
         }
};
```

Note that `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` is sent by a sticky broadcast, meaning that as soon as the broadcast receiver is registered (likely when the activity is started), you will receive a value from the last time the intent was updated. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092438/intent-action-headset-plug-is-received-when-activity-starts) for more details.